# Yamaha 200 HP outboard Ox66 tilt/trim unit frozen screws

Tags: yamaha, boat

[image]

I have a Yamaha 200 HP Ox66 attached to a 1986 Mako 20. My tilt/trim unit has been sitting in saltwater in South Florida for some 4 years.
I did a piston rebuilt with new gaskets, seals etc some 2 years ago. But recently I found a galvanic corrosion bullet hole on the body, so I had to take the boat out of the water to replace the tilt unit. I am not a professional mechanic, but I own some tools, and this is my 4th boat, plus helping friends with boats around.
Also, I allocate time to read service manuals and YouTube a lot.

I bought a functioning unit on eBay with some signs of wear and tear, but overall good condition, since new units for this engines are overly and absurdly expensive. Replaced the 2 pistons with new piston sub assembly (the works). Now I have a little leak on the reservoir, and carefully unscrew 2 screws, and the third one snapped flush to the metal. Fine, drilled a hole in the center, insert an Irwin "top rated" screw extractor and spin it very carefully and. Snapped too.

So now I have a broken steel screw with a very hard screw extractor in the center, ...
Undeterred, drilled an offset hole, thread a new screw, and problem solved. No leaks!

But, after flushing air bubbles, etc, the unit is acting very erratic, like there is something clogged. I am aware that there is a filter under the motor, since there is only 4 screws that came out very easily in my original unit, I go ahead and now I have 2 broken screws! managed to drill hole dead center on both screws (1/4 -20 ), insert a brand new extractor on one and it breaks. Now I have a stainless steel screw with a broken extractor made of a fairly hard alloy in the center of it. I cannot use a torch because of o rings, seals etc.
Attaching some pics. Any ideas? All you-tube videos get to the part where screws ideally come out very nicely. Not my case!

The whole thing and procedures have been soaked in pb blaster and wd 40 for hours and hours, tapped the screws, tapped the metal, spray again...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this: https://jalopnik.com/heres-how-you-remove-a-fractured-bolt-extractor-tip-fro-1746998630

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be get all of it out, then drill it oversize and Helicoil it. I don't thing you're going to get it out any other way then by using heat. Even if you have to remove the o-rings or whatever rubber is present.

Comment: Thank you guys, for the suggestions . I have a dremel, that sounds like a good idea. I will keep you posted!

Comment: Don't bother with the WD-40, it's not even penetrating oil.  It's sold as a "jack of all trades" but it's a master of none.  Well, that's not entirely fair.  It was optimized (**40** iterations, in fact) to keep condensation off missiles in damp underground silos.   All the rest is marketing horsepuckey.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the advice regarding the dremel, that worked out. I was able to grind down the broken bit enough to break it into pieces and get it out. Then corrected the hole again, and re-thread it. All good now[image]

[image]